# Use subdomain for certain urls

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, apache

I have the following rules in my .htaccess file on a WordPress (single installation):

```
# REWRITE FORUMS DOMAIN TO FOLDER
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forums\.example\.com$
RewriteRule !^forums/? forums%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]

# REWRITE FORUMS FOLDER TO SUBDOMAIN
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/forums/([^\s]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://forums.example.com/%1 [R=301,L]
```

This is so that the forums that exist at `http://example.com/forums` are accessed at `http://forums.example.com/`

However the server just blows up with a 500 server error...

Any ideas on how to do this? **These rules work perfectly when used on non-wordpress sites...** The second rewrite rules successfully send /forums to the sub domain but the subdomain doesn't seem to be able to pass the data into WordPress correctly.'

The whole htaccess file looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# REWRITE FORUMS DOMAIN TO FOLDER
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forums\.example\.com$
RewriteRule !^forums/? forums%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]

# REWRITE FORUMS FOLDER TO SUBDOMAIN
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/forums/([^\s]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://forums.example.com/%1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress

</IfModule>
```

**The reason that the WordPress rules are after the forums rules are because if I put them after then they are never hit!**

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested):

```
# BEGIN Forums Rewrite
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ forums/%1
# END Forums Rewrite
```

It should work with both your requirements. You don't need the second one (rewriting the forums folder to subdomain) because rewriting the actual forum ID will override the basic subdomain rewriting `forums.domain.com/forumid=16`.

You should add these lines after those generated by WordPress.

Comment: Can you explain what each line is doing (and why I don't need to rewrite the folder to the subdomain). Thanks.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Try the lines and see of they work. Also, do you have mod_rewrite active on your server? Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: Tried that but doesn't do anything. Forums are sill accessed at `/forums` and the sub domain just acts like a wildcard and doesn't rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not very trivial to do. You need to take into account that wordpress needs the "forums" directory in the url to successfully detect that the requested content is forum post and not regular posts or pages. Therefor you need to change the value of `REQUEST_URI` in the htaccess file or add your own URL parsing code.

the path of least resistance for this kind of configuration may be to have a mutisite install and activate the forums on their own site. It probably will be more straight forward to share data themes and plugins between sites the to handle everything related to url rewriting and parsing yourself

Comment: I really don't want to use MU for this... so if it's possible I'd like to do it with the htaccess file... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I offer following solution. It's required prepending this lines to index.php.

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'])) {
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'];
}
```

I know this is a dirty hack, but WordPress rewrite mechanism based on `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` value.

These rules tested only on links like (with another domain) http://example.com/forums/ and http://forums.example.com/
Let me know if it not works on other links.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# WordPress native stop rule
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# prepend subdomain prefix
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forums\.example\.coml$
RewriteRule !^forums/? forums%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]

# redirect to subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^forums\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/forums/(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://forums.example.com/%1 [R=301,L]

# WordPress native rewrite with avoiding existing file- and dir- links
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# avoid rewrite endless loop (to be on the safe side)
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. `http://forums.example.com/` and `http://www.example.com/` show the home page. And `http://forums.example.com/forums/` and `http://www.example.com/forums/` show the forums.

Comment: What is Apache version?

Comment: @ tutankhamun Apache: 2.2.22

Answer (score 0):

If I can offer an alternative solution, there is a plugin in the repository that will map domains or subdomains on the WordPress side.  I use the [Multiple Domains](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-domain-mapping-on-single-site/) plugin by Matthias Wagner to do something very similar on one of my sites.

To set this up, just have the subdomain point to your WordPress installation, which you apparently already do.  Within the plugin settings, add your mapping to map `http://forums.example.com` to `http://www.example.com/forums`.

Using this plugin (or another like it) has the added benefit that WordPress “recognizes” the mapping such that your forum posts will report their canonical URI with the subdomain rather than the main domain.  This may not be critical in your application, but it will help search engines and other bots to identify your forum posts with your chosen URI rather than the default WordPress location.